# How to get device ID of DSTH01 I2C Communication?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic, i2c

I am trying to get the humidity and temperature using DSTH01. But I am not able to get the proper value .I am getting Humidity as -24 and Temperature as -50. I don't know where I am missing. Please guide me to resolve my problem. Initially if I get the Device ID that will help to solve my problem. I am using PIC18f2520 with 10 MHz crystal.

I have done the following connection:

```
 PIN1-GND
 PIN2-Pull Up to 3.3 V with 10k- Microcontroller  PIN_C3
 PIN3 - Pull Up to 3.3 V with 10k-Microcontroller  PIN_C4
 PIN4 - Microcontroller  PIN_A2
 PIN5 - 3.3 V
```

Here is my source code:

```
 #define DSTH01_SCK  PIN_C3
 #define DSTH01_SDA  PIN_C4
 #define DSTH01_CSB  PIN_A2

 #define SDA_H output_high(DSTH01_SDA)
 #define SDA_L output_low(DSTH01_SDA)
 #define SCK_H output_high(DSTH01_SCK)
 #define SCK_L output_low(DSTH01_SCK)
 #define CS_H  output_high(DSTH01_CSB)
 #define CS_L  output_low(DSTH01_CSB)

 #define SlaveAddress      0x40
 #define RegisterAddress0  0x00
 #define RegisterAddress1  0x01
 #define RegisterAddress2  0x02
 #define RegisterAddress3  0x03
 #define RegisterAddress11 0x11

 void small_delay(void);
 void I2C_START(void);
 void I2C_STOP(void);
 void I2C_WRITE(unsigned int8 Data);
 int8 I2C_READ(void);
 void I2C_ACK(unsigned int8 a);
 int8 I2C_SEND(unsigned int8 SlaveAdd,unsigned int8 RegisterAdd,unsigned  int8 *s);
 int8 I2C_RECEIVE(unsigned int8 SlaveAdd,unsigned int8 RegisterAdd,unsigned int8 *s);
 void Temperature_READ(unsigned int8 *s);
 void RelativeHumidity_READ(unsigned int8 *s);
 int1 Check_SDA(void);

 unsigned int8 Ack;
 unsigned int8 id;
 unsigned int8 RelativeHumidity =0;
 unsigned int8 Temperature =0;
 unsigned int8 Start1=0x01;
 unsigned int8 Start2=0x11;

 void main(void)
 {    
     set_tris_c(0x80);
     delay_ms(100);delay_ms(100);  
     output_low(PIN_C3);
     output_high(PIN_C4);
     output_low(PIN_A2);
     enable_interrupts(int_rda);
     enable_interrupts(global);   
     delay_ms(100);delay_ms(100);
     delay_ms(100);delay_ms(100);
     delay_ms(100);delay_ms(100);  

     CS_L;
     I2C_RECEIVE(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress11,&id);
     while (1)
     {
            RelativeHumidity_READ(&RelativeHumidity);
            Temperature_READ(&Temperature);
            delay_ms(100);delay_ms(100);
            delay_ms(100);delay_ms(100);
            delay_ms(100);delay_ms(100);
            printf("\r\nRelativeHumidity:%d",RelativeHumidity);
            printf("\tTemperature:%d",Temperature);
      }  
  }

void I2C_START()
{
   SDA_H;small_delay();
   SCK_H;small_delay();
   SDA_L;small_delay();
   SCK_L;small_delay();
 }
void I2C_STOP()
{
   SDA_L;small_delay();
   SCK_H;small_delay();
   SDA_H;small_delay();
}  
 void I2C_WRITE(unsigned  int8 Data)
{
   unsigned  int8 i;
   for(i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
      if(Data&0x80)
         {SDA_H;small_delay();}
      else
         SDA_L;small_delay();
         SCK_H;small_delay();
         SCK_L;small_delay();
         Data<<=1;
   }
   SDA_H;small_delay();
   SCK_H;small_delay();
   //if(SDA==1)
   if(Check_SDA()==1)
      Ack=0;
   else
      Ack=1;
      SCK_L;small_delay();
}  
unsigned  int8 I2C_READ()
{
   unsigned  int8 Data=0;
   unsigned  int8 i;
   SDA_H;
   for(i=0;i<8;i++)
   {
      SCK_L;small_delay();
      SCK_H;small_delay();
      Data<<=1;
      //if(SDA==1)
     if(Check_SDA()==1)
      Data=Data+1; 
   }
   SCK_L;small_delay();
   return Data;
}
void I2C_ACK(unsigned  int8 a)
{
   if(a==0)
      {SDA_L;small_delay();}
   else
      SDA_H;small_delay();
      SCK_H;small_delay();
   SCK_L;small_delay();
}
unsigned int8 I2C_SEND(unsigned  int8 SlaveAdd,unsigned  int8 RegisterAdd,unsigned  int8 *s)
{
   SlaveAdd=SlaveAdd<<1;
   I2C_START();
   I2C_WRITE(SlaveAdd);
   if(Ack==0)
      return 0;
   I2C_WRITE(RegisterAdd);
      if(Ack==0)
         return 0;
      I2C_WRITE(*s);
         if(Ack==0)
         return 0;
         I2C_STOP();
   return 1;
}
unsigned  int8 I2C_RECEIVE(unsigned  int8 SlaveAdd,unsigned  int8 RegisterAdd,unsigned  int8 *s)
{
   SlaveAdd = SlaveAdd<<1;
   I2C_START();
   I2C_WRITE(SlaveAdd);
   if(Ack==0)
   return 0;
   I2C_WRITE(RegisterAdd);
   if(Ack==0)
   return 0;
   I2C_START();

   I2C_WRITE(SlaveAdd+1);
   if(Ack==0)
      return 0;
      *s=I2C_READ();
      I2C_ACK(1);
      I2C_STOP();
   return 1;
}
void RelativeHumidity_READ(unsigned  int8 *s)
{
   unsigned  int8 Status=1;
   unsigned  int8 RelativeHumidityH;
   unsigned  int8 RelativeHumidityL;
   unsigned  int16 RelHum;
   I2C_SEND(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress3,&Start1);
   while(Status==1)
   {
      I2C_RECEIVE(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress0,&Status);
   }
   I2C_RECEIVE(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress1,&RelativeHumidityH);
   I2C_RECEIVE(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress2,&RelativeHumidityL);
   RelHum=RelativeHumidityH;
   RelHum=RelHum<<8;
   RelHum+=RelativeHumidityL;
   RelHum=RelHum>>4;
   *s=RelHum/16-24;
}
void Temperature_READ(unsigned  int8 *s)
{
   unsigned  int8 Status=1;
   unsigned  int8 TemperatureH;
   unsigned  int8 TemperatureL;
   unsigned  int16 Temp;
   I2C_SEND(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress3,&Start2);
   while(Status==1)
   {
      I2C_RECEIVE(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress0,&Status);
   }
   I2C_RECEIVE(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress1,&TemperatureH);
   I2C_RECEIVE(SlaveAddress,RegisterAddress2,&TemperatureL);
   Temp=TemperatureH;
   Temp<<=8;
   Temp+=TemperatureL;
   Temp>>=2;
   *s=Temp/32-50;
}
int1 Check_SDA(void)
{
   int1 a;
   set_tris_c(0x90);//10010000,RX,0,0,SDA,0,0,0,0
   small_delay();
   if(input(DSTH01_SDA)){a =1; }
   else{a = 0;}
   set_tris_c(0x80);//10000000
   small_delay();
   return a;
}
void small_delay(void)
{
   char a;
   for(a = 0;a < 10;a++);
}
```

Comment: How can you be getting negative values from `unsigned` variables?

Comment: Use printf `%u` to print `unsigned int`s

Comment: Anyone could tell me why I am getting -Ve Marks ? Is there any problem with my question?   Here id the Datasheet " www.dorji.com/docs/data/DSTH01.pdf" ..Please do reply.

Comment: @RFK I originally posted an answer after reading that same data sheet, but deleted it due to uncertainty. I found at least one error in the data sheet (Table 8 which instead of showing Temperature repeats Table 6 for Humidity). I noticed some code on there which you might have copied, maybe that is faulty too. I suggested you try reading the values and displaying them (in hexadecimal or binary) without any shifting or adjustment to see for yourself what correlation you get between various inputs and the data received. Be methodical about it.

Comment: @RFK I undeleted an earlier answer, in which I thought you might be duplicating the data shifting required by also dividing. If it is a red herring, so sorry, tell me and I will delete it again.

Comment: @Weather Vane thanks for your reply. You need not to delete it. Yes you are correct ..there are some errors in the datasheet.Please see my answer I have already posted. If you like please give some +ve merks thats all.

Comment: @RFK please "Accept" my answer if it was correct and helped you.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** I previously deleted this answer because I thought it was **faulty** and **useless**, but perhaps there is something here for OP after all ...

How can you be getting negative values from `unsigned` variables?

Looking at the [DSTH01 data sheet](http://www.dorji.com/docs/data/DSTH01.pdf), % relative humidity is calculated by *`(RH/16)-24`* and this suggests your code has an unnecessary line

```
RelHum=RelHum>>4;               // remove this line
*s=RelHum/16-24;
```

Next, the data sheet says that temperature is calulated by *`(TEMP/32)-50`* and this suggests your code has another unnecessary line

```
Temp>>=2;                       // remove this line
*s=Temp/32-50;
```

assuming you have read the I2C data correctly.

The data sheet has an error in Table 6 which shows Humidity to be 11 bits. It also has an error in Table 8 which instead of showing Temperature repeats the same table as for Humidity, Table 6.

I think you are doing the extra divisions because the data sheet says the results are 12-bit and 14-bit respectively, but the inference is that the data is left-aligned, which is why the divisions (actually shifts) are required - but only once! I suggest you do the conversions as the data sheet says: use `DATAh` & `DATAl` and these are zero-padded on the right. So the code might be better as

```
RelHum = (RelHum >> 4) - 24;    // div 16
*s = (unsigned int8)RelHum;     // now cast to 8-bit
```

and

```
Temp = (Temp >> 5) - 50;        // div 32
*s = (unsigned int8)Temp;       // now cast to 8-bit
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your valuable support and suggestion. I have left the bit banging method. Tried the hardware feature. Finally I got the results. This is the code snippet :-

```
i2c_start();
i2c_write(0x80); // Device address
i2c_write(0x11); // Data to device
i2c_start(); // Restart
i2c_write(0x81); // to change data direction
data=i2c_read(0); // Now read from slave
printf("\n\rID:%02X",data);
i2c_stop();
```